# application call . TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, url, include, admin

I am taking a course where this error does not occur
my error is cod is:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bo
otstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run

    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\auto
reload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\manag
ement\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\manag
ement\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\manag
ement\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\check
s\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\check
s\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\check
s\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resol
vers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\func
tional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resol
vers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\func
tional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resol
vers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 12
7, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\KursDjango\skcms\skcms\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'article/',include('articles.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.
py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 12
7, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\KursDjango\skcms\articles\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    url(r'^show_all/$', 'articles.views.articles'),
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\
__init__.py", line 13, in url
    return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "C:\Users\wuoel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.
py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

urls.py

> from django.conf.urls import include, url from django.urls import
>   include
>
> urlpatterns =('',
>       url(r'article/',include('articles.urls')) )

articles/urls.py

> from django.conf.urls import *
>
> urlpatterns =('',
>       url(r'^show_all/$', 'articles.views.articles'),
>       url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', 'articles.views.article'), )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is explained in this way:

skcms/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns =[
    path('article/',include('articles.urls')),  
]
```

articles/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.articles, name='articles'),
    path('', views.article, name='article'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the string representation of the name to `include()` rather than the actual articles.urls variable. Instead, it should look something like this:

```
from articles import urls as article_urls 

...

urlpatterns =[
   url(r'article/',include(article_urls, namespace='article'))
]
```

Comment: still the same mistake

Comment: the ruler does not light up: from articles import urls as article_urls .
when I get to 'urls'

Comment: I'd need to see the file structure of your app and maybe your `settings.py` to help further. Also there was a typo in my response that I just fixed, so `include(article.urls` became `include(article_urls` so that could also help. If you have an app folder named 'articles' and you have articles listed as an internal app in your settings.py this _should_ work. Is your articles app registered in `settings.py`?

Comment: it look like this : INSTALLED_APPS = [
'articles',
]

Comment: articles/urls.py :
urlpatterns =('',
    url(r'^show_all/$', 'articles.views.articles'),
    url(r'^(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'articles.views.article'),
)